# Pure CSS nested accordion doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make [this pure CSS accordion](https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/ihlDf).

[My version](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjXNxK)

Why it does not work? What do I need to change to make it work?

I tried this:

**HTML without CSS:**

```
      <h1>CSS + HTML only Accordion Element</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <i></i>
      <h2>Languages Used</h2>
      <p>This page was written in HTML and CSS. The CSS was compiled from SASS. I used Normalize as my CSS reset and -prefix-free to save myself some headaches. I haven't quite gotten the hang of Slim for compiling into HTML, but someday I'll use it since its syntax compliments that of SASS. Regardless, this could all be done in plain HTML and CSS.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <i></i>
      <h2>How it Works</h2>
      <p>Using the sibling and checked selectors, we can determine the styling of sibling elements based on the checked state of the checkbox input element. One use, as demonstrated here, is an entirely CSS and HTML accordion element. Media queries are used to make the element responsive to different screen sizes.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>
      <i></i>
      <h2>Points of Interest</h2>
      <p>
                <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <i></i>
                <h2>Languages Used</h2>
                <p>This page was written in HTML and CSS. The CSS was compiled from SASS. I used Normalize as my CSS reset and -prefix-free to save myself some headaches. I haven't quite gotten the hang of Slim for compiling into HTML, but someday I'll use it since its syntax compliments that of SASS. Regardless, this could all be done in plain HTML and CSS.</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <i></i>
                <h2>How it Works</h2>
                <p>Using the sibling and checked selectors, we can determine the styling of sibling elements based on the checked state of the checkbox input element. One use, as demonstrated here, is an entirely CSS and HTML accordion element. Media queries are used to make the element responsive to different screen sizes.</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <i></i>
                <h2>Points of Interest</h2>
                <p></p>
              </li>
            </ul>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**HTML with CSS:**

```
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>

      </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="interlocuteurs/css/layout_1_column.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

      <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,700,300italic'>

          <style>
          /* NOTE: The styles were added inline because Prefixfree needs access to your styles and they must be inlined if they are on local disk! */
          .transition, p, ul li i:before, ul li i:after {
      transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    }

    .flipIn, h1, ul li {
      animation: flipdown 0.5s ease both;
    }

    .no-select, h2 {
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      perspective: 900;
      overflow-y: scroll;
      background-color: #dce7eb;
      font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
      color: rgba(48, 69, 92, 0.8);
    }

    body {
      min-height: 0;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      margin: 90px 0;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 #008ae6 inset;
      background-color: #fefffa;
      max-width: 80%;
      padding: 30px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 550px) {
      body {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transform: translate(0, 0);
        max-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
    }

    h1, h2 {
      color: #008ae6;
    }

    h1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 36px;
      line-height: 42px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      font-weight: 100;
    }

    h2 {
      font-size: 26px;
      line-height: 34px;
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      display: block;
      background-color: #fefffa;
      margin: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    p {
      color: rgba(48, 69, 92, 0.8);
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 26px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      max-height: 800px;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translate(0, 0);
      margin-top: 14px;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      perspective: 900;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul li {
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding-bottom: 4px;
      padding-top: 18px;
      border-top: 1px dotted #dce7eb;
    }
    ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
      animation-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
      animation-delay: 0.75s;
    }
    ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }
    ul li:last-of-type {
      padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    ul li i {
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-6px, 0);
      margin-top: 16px;
      right: 0;
    }
    ul li i:before, ul li i:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #008ae6;
      width: 3px;
      height: 9px;
    }
    ul li i:before {
      transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    }
    ul li i:after {
      transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    ul li input[type=checkbox] {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
      margin-top: 0;
      max-height: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate(0, 50%);
    }
    ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:before {
      transform: translate(2px, 0) rotate(45deg);
    }
    ul li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ i:after {
      transform: translate(-2px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
    }

    @keyframes flipdown {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform-origin: top center;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      80% {
        transform: rotateX(8deg);
      }
      83% {
        transform: rotateX(6deg);
      }
      92% {
        transform: rotateX(-3deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform-origin: top center;
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
      }
    }

        </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Comment: I tried here and it works perfectly, check your browser version...

Comment: here ? where is it :)

Comment: You need to hide the nested `ul` by default, right now it is just set to display with the parent `li`.

Comment: I tried online with chrome and firefox. Didn't try on my machine, will do it and then come back.

Comment: Your codepen link is working for me in the most recent version of Chrome.

Comment: You should know how this site works by now. We need a [mcve], in the question itself.

Comment: @shanzilla it is working but it is not nested

Comment: @user310291 it's nested, it's just that you don't have any styling set for the nested `ul`, it is being treated the same way as the parent `ul`.

Comment: @APAD1 I'm css beginner I tried to add style ul.hidden {display: none;} but doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you're a CSS beginner you should copy the compiled CSS and make a new fork without using a pre-processor, it will be much easier for you.

Comment: [This should get you started](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrVRYr). From here I would suggest adding additional left padding to the nested `ul` so that the hierarchy is clear. Possibly even change the colors or other styling to further differentiate it from the parent items. You will also need to figure out how to display the nested list with animation when you click on the parent element.

Comment: @APAD1 I don't understand : last item is blank ? https://snag.gy/5a2gTj.jpg

Comment: It's blank because the animation is set to work on `p` tags within the parent `li`, you will need to adapt it for it to work on the (now hidden) `ul`. Unfortunately, it's not as simple as just wrapping the `ul` in a `p` tag because `ul`s are not valid children of `p` tags.

Comment: @APAD1 you mean I need to use some javascript ? Can't I just make it work with pure Css ?

Comment: Essential reading (especially for a 10K user): [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjXNqR) that works, with the following updated CSS and markup, where the trick is to only target the first div on each input (also swapped `p` for `div` for a valid sub structure)

<strike>What I did was to add a class for each level (`lev1`/`lev2`), applied to both the `input` and the `div`, which makes it possible show/hide one level at the time, and then use the very same in the CSS</strike>

*After a second thought I saw a class per level was not necessary so I simplified it*

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox]
  position: absolute
  cursor: pointer
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  z-index: 1
  opacity: 0

  &:checked

    &~div
      margin-top: 0
      max-height: 0
      opacity: 0
      transform: translate( 0 , 50% )
```

HTML

```
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <i></i>
    <h2>Points of Interest</h2>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <i></i>
          <h2>Sub 1 Points of Interest</h2>
          <div>....</div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" checked>
          <i></i>
          <h2>Sub 2 Points of Interest</h2>
          <div>....</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: @user310291 Ahh, now I see ... took that for an improper formatted markup ... will have a look and see how to make that work

Answer (score 0):

Remove that weird ul tag, and write

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

, there shouldn't be that  at all.

Just remove it and keep HTML markup as it was in original codepen example.
And your pen will work perfectly (except animation on loading, because you didn't set for all li childrens, only for 3).

Comment: what do you mean ? Sorry I'm css beginner I don't understand.

Comment: @user310291 i wrote same as a guy before me. I am glad it worked for you. :)